# Anything change with Google Apps Scripts or Visualization API in the last 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

On Thursday 4/7/2016 around mid-day I lost functionality for all new instances of one of my Google Script WebApps.

I use `google.visualization.Query(`... from called from JavaScript extensively for quick searches through large Google Sheets files.

As of the writing of this post, one previously loaded instance of the webapp is still running successfully, but all newly loaded instances fail.  I have pulled the source code for that working instance, and it is identical to the non-functioning instances.  I've created a new project and the new project instance (with identical code) also fails across all browsers.

I'm puzzled..

Here's a snippet of code I'm suspicious of.  It's a recursive function that queries two sheets on one spreadsheet (building and built), then queries another sheet from a different spreadsheet (archive), and sets the result to 3 datatables.

```
function queryThings(response)
{
    // If this is the first call to query 
    if(response == null)
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem("qIndex_H", "0");

        // Building Query
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(s_thingsBuilding + '&tq=select+*+where+LOWER(' + key1 + ')+contains+%27' + sessionStorage.getItem("stringInput") + '%27');
        query.send(querythings);

        return;
    }

    // if This is the second call
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("qIndex_H") == "0")
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem("qIndex_H", "1");

        //Store build sheet dataTable in sessionStorage 
        sessionStorage.setItem("thingTable1", response.getDataTable().toJSON());

        // Show or hide the div
        if(response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows() > 0)
            $("#thingsBuilding").show();
        else
            $("#thingsBuilding").hide();

        var query = new google.visualization.Query(s_thingsBuilt + '&tq=select+*+where+LOWER(' + key1 + ')+contains+%27' + sessionStorage.getItem("stringInput") + '%27');
        query.send(querythings);

        return;
    }

    // if This is the third call
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("qIndex_H") == "1")
    {           
        sessionStorage.setItem("qIndex_H", "2");

        //Store build sheet dataTable in sessionStorage 
        sessionStorage.setItem("thingTable2", response.getDataTable().toJSON());

        // Show or hide the div
        if(response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows() > 0)
            $("#thingsBuilt").show();
        else
            $("#thingsBuilt").hide();

        var query = new google.visualization.Query(s_thingsArchive + '&tq=select+*+where+LOWER(' + key1 + ')+contains+%27' + sessionStorage.getItem("stringInput") + '%27');
        query.send(querythings);

        return;
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem("qIndex_H", "0");

    var dt1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(sessionStorage.getItem("thingTable1"));
    var dt2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(sessionStorage.getItem("thingTable2"));

    // Show or hide the div
    if(response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows() > 0)
        $("#thingsArchive").show();
    else
        $("#thingsArchive").hide();

    if(dt1.getNumberOfRows() + dt2.getNumberOfRows() + response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows() == 0)
        $("#thingsDiv").hide();

    setTable_DT(dt1, "thingsBuilding");
    setTable_DT(dt2, "thingsBuilt");
    setTable_DT(response.getDataTable(), "thingsArchive");
}
```

Console Output:

> Uncaught Error: Missing query for request id: 0VM60 userCodeAppPanel:170
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of nullqueryThings @ VM60   userCodeAppPanel:170R.eC @   format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:288xw @   format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:283(anonymous function) @    format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:287
>   VM60 userCodeAppPanel:243
>   ...
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of null
>   ...

In the past, I have had my Google Apps Script code crash for a few hours, only for functionality to return on its own.  Does anyone know of any recent changes to the API that might have affected my code? I don't think it's browser related because it's failing on IE, Firefox and Chrome.  The one working previously loaded instance is loaded on Chrome.  Admittedly, I don't have much error checking code in this file, but process of elimination has me suspicious of an update to Apps Script or Visualization API.

### Thanks

Max

Comment: don't think it's the Visualization API, currently building a dashboard, ran fine all day 4/7

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly loading the "Table" and "Corechart" Visualization packages.

Admittedly, it was pretty sloppy, but I'm still not sure why it worked yesterday, but not today.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["table"]});
```

Was replaced with

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["table", "corechart"]});
```

My guess is that the "Corechart" package was being over-written by the "Table" package.

Comment: The fact is, my code was badly written.  Still there must have been a change that caused this to break.

I would be very interested to hear any insight as to what that was that change might have been.